# MySQL Foreign Key Not Cascading On Delete

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, coupon:

```
CREATE TABLE `coupon` (
  `coupon_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `logged` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `date_start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `date_end` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `uses_total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uses_customer` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`coupon_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code_u_idx` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and offers:

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(96) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `telephone` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `contacted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `approved` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `offers_code_foreign` (`code`),
  CONSTRAINT `offers_code_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) 
  REFERENCES `coupon` (`code`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The workflow for these tables is as follows:

1. Customer creates an offer on a product from the front of the website.
2. Admin then calls the customer, verifies their info, generates a coupon, and gives it to the customer over the phone and updates the offer entry.

In other words the coupon is not generated with the offer, it's generated after and the offer entry updated.

This seems like it should work fine, but when I delete an offer, the coupon is not getting deleted via the `CASCADE` and I can't figure out why.

Am I missing something in my table set up that would make MySQL ignore the constraint?

Thanks

Comment: How can an offer be inserted after a coupon? You have the FK reversed it seems. Or you can keep it as it is but when you want them (offer and coupon) deleted, delete from the `coupon`, not from `offer`.

Comment: Where do you see that it says the offer is created after the coupon? `the coupon is not generated with the offer, it's generated after`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I read only the `CREATE TABLE` statements when answered. With only that, seemed to be the logical order. But anyway, the 2nd part of my comment still applies. What happens if you delete the coupon? Isn't the related offer also deleted?